# Constraints issue in Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, constraints

I'm having some issues with the constraints in my app. Here is how it looks on the iPhone 4 (that's how i want it to look, and how i usually setup my interface, is this the proper approach or not?)
[image: iPhone pre-5]

Now, when i switch to the iPhone 5 screen it looks like this
[image: iPhone 5]

and as you can see, the blue dots (which is UIButtons) are not placed where i want them to be. I made my constraints rely solely on the right side of the view (since that is the one re-sizing, i found that in order for you'r views to align themselves accordingly, it doesn't help to align them to the left side). I don't really know how to fix this. I am finding this new iPhone screen to be a real pain in the arse. Any good advice on how to work with this new screen without a lot of headache would be appreciated :)

Thanks on advance

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the are still the same distance from the right side of your view, as you said you set them to be, while the background has stretched to fit the new size. I suspect it's actually the background that isn't doing what you want it to do (keep the same aspect ratio and show more stuff on the left), or try keeping the buttons relating to left and right to stay aligned with the stretched background image.

Comment: Yeah it actually looks like it's the image that isn't doing what it's supposed to, but how can i change that? i can see that it actually just makes the road wider, but i have no clue on how to make this fit properly. I don't understand what u mean by aligning the buttons differently? can you elaborate? and thanks mate